# How to define UDF STRICTLY USING SPARK SQL with the mentioned requirement

Tags: apache-spark

Duration – Duration of trip
Start Date – Includes start date and time
End Date – Includes end date and time
Start Station – Includes starting station name and number
End Station – Includes ending station name and number
Bike Number – Includes ID number of bike used for the trip
Member Type – Indicates whether user was a "registered" member (Annual Member,
30-Day Member or Day Key Member) or a "casual" rider (Single trip, 24-Hour Pass, 3-Day Pass
or 5-Day Pass)

question is how to define UDF STRICTLY USING SPARK SQL to:
○ Convert the Start Station and End Station to UPPER case.
○ Generate columns
■ ‘start_day’ in format "mm-dd-YY",
■ ‘quarter_of_day’,
■ ‘is_weekend’
… all of the above using 'Start date' column.

i tried every way but itz not happening

Answer (score 0):

In the below example I took sample data. I implemented UDF functions and registered to the SparkSession, and used these udf's in spark sql.

I took a sample data based on the information you provided. You can post your code as well so that we will come to what is missing.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[4]")
      .appName("Remove-String-From-One-DF-From-Another").getOrCreate()


    import spark.implicits._


    val tripDF1 = Seq(
      ("8", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-12 03:04:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-12 03:12:00"), "washington", "roslyn", "01010101", "Annual Member"),
      ("60", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-13 11:04:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-13 12:04:00"), "reston", "ashburn", "01010102", "casual"),
      ("20", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-14 19:04:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-14 19:24:00"), "Boston ", "roslyn", "01010103", "30 Day Member"),
      ("30", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-12 03:14:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-12 03:44:00"), "Philadelphia ", "Washington", "01010104", "Annual Member"),
      ("17", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-11 12:04:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-11 12:21:00"), "Baltimore", "Washington", "01010105", "casual"),
      ("30", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:30:00"), "washington", "Miami ", "01010106", "30 Day Member"),
      ("20", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:30:00"), "Cincinnati", "Chicago", "01010107", "casual"),
      ("10", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:20:00"), "Raleigh", "Charlotte", "01010108", "30 Day Member"),
      ("30", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:30:00"), "washington", "Miami ", "01010106", "30 Day Member"),
      ("20", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:30:00"), "Cincinnati", "Chicago", "01010107", "casual"),
      ("10", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:20:00"), "Raleigh", "Charlotte", "01010108", "30 Day Member"),
      ("30", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-15 05:30:00"), "washington", "Miami ", "01010106", "30 Day Member"),
      ("20", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-16 07:30:00"), "Cincinnati", "Chicago", "01010107", "casual"),
      ("10", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:10:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2017-02-17 17:20:00"), "Raleigh", "Charlotte", "01010108", "30 Day Member")
    ).toDF("Duration", "StartDate", "EndDate", "StartStation", "EndStation", "BikeNumber", "MemberType")



    spark.udf.register("upperCase", (inputString: String) => inputString.toUpperCase())
    tripDF1.show()

    tripDF1.createOrReplaceTempView("TRIPS")

    spark.sql(" Select " +
      "Duration, " +
      "StartDate, " +
      "to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(StartDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as TIMESTAMP)) as converted_StartDate, " +
      "EndDate, " +
      "to_date(CAST(unix_timestamp(EndDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as TIMESTAMP)) as converted_EndDate,  " +
      "date_format(EndDate, 'E') as day_of_week, " +

      "case date_format(EndDate, 'E') " +
      "when 'Sat' then 'Yes' " +
      "when 'Sun' then 'Yes' " +
      "else 'No' end as Derived_WeekDayOrNot, " +
      "upperCase(StartStation), " +
      "upperCase(EndStation), " +
      "BikeNumber, " +
      "MemberType  " +
      "from TRIPS").show()





  }
```